# ansible can't replace string lineinfile

Tags: ansible

I am still confused about why the string can't replace it instead creates a new line. so i want to replace default h2 connection url to be sql connection as follow

```
- name: replace h2 db connection to sql connection
lineinfile:
  dest: "configuration/standalone.xml"
  regexp: '^\$<connection-url>jdbc:h2:${jboss.server.data.dir}/keycloak;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</connection-url>'
  line: '<connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=mydatabase;integratedSecurity=false;user=myuser;password=mypassword</connection-url>'
```

Comment: It looks like you escaped one `$` but left the occurrence after `h2:`; the `{` character is also meaningful in regex, so you'd want to escape that too. The [`| regex_escape`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) filter may interest you. Also, as written that assumes the line starts with `$<conn` which I guess anything is possible but would be very weird for an xml file

Comment: Test your regex with https://regexr.com/, there's an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
---

- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/out
        regexp: '^<connection-url>jdbc:.*<\/connection-url>'
        line: >-
          {{ _format | format(
            _db_mode,
            _db_host,
            _db_port,
            _db_name,
            _db_user,
            _db_password,
            _db_options)
          }}
      vars:
        _format: >-
          <connection-url>jdbc:%s://%s:%s;databaseName=%s;user=%s;password=%s;%s</connection-url>
        _db_mode: sqlserver
        _db_host: localhost
        _db_port: 1433
        _db_name: mydatabase
        _db_user: myuser
        _db_password: mypassword
        _db_options: integratedSecurity=false
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work, even trying to remove the <connection-url> tags with the following command is still there

`code
 - name: remove h2 db connection
    lineinfile:
      dest: "configuration/standalone.xml"
      regexp: '^<connection-url>jdbc:.*</connection-url>'
      state: absent
`

Comment: sorted out now, in regexp add * after ^ so the command like this :

`code
regexp:  '^ *<connection-url>jdbc:.*<\/connection-url>'`

Comment: I don't know what is your exact input line, you did not show it.